# PHP gnupg_addsignkey Error: get_key failed

Tags: php, cryptography, gnupg, pgp

```
<?php

$res = gnupg_init();

gnupg_clearsignkeys($res);

$key = get_pub_key();// Value pasted below

$publicImp = gnupg_import($res, $key);

gnupg_addsignkey($res, $publicImp['fingerprint']);

echo gnupg_geterror($res); // Prints `get_key failed`
```

The key is generated from https://www.igolder.com/pgp/generate-key/

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0
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=pvzn
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The key info looks like this.

```
[fingerprint] => AF4A061F20FFFE141AA366FE586DCFCD529A884E
[keyid] => 586DCFCD529A884E
[timestamp] => 1573215581
[expires] => 0
[is_secret] =>
[invalid] =>
[can_encrypt] => 1
[can_sign] => 1
[disabled] =>
[expired] =>
[revoked] =>
```

Could not find any solution, kindly help.

Comment: Looks like a file permission issue: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gnupg-init.php#121851 https://board.phpbuilder.com/d/10384574-resolved-newbie-using-php-and-gnupg/5

Answer (score 5):

In order for this to work you need to import the private key also.

According to https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c235.html:

> ### Key Integrity
>
> When you distribute your public key, you are distributing the public
>   components of your master and subordinate keys as well as the user
>   IDs. Distributing this material alone, however, is a security risk
>   since it is possible for an attacker to tamper with the key. The
>   public key can be modified by adding or substituting keys, or by
>   adding or changing user IDs. By tampering with a user ID, the attacker
>   could change the user ID's email address to have email redirected to
>   himself. By changing one of the encryption keys, the attacker would
>   also be able to decrypt the messages redirected to him.
>
> Using digital signatures is a solution to this problem. When data is
>   signed by a private key, the corresponding public key is bound to the
>   signed data. In other words, only the corresponding public key can be
>   used to verify the signature and ensure that the data has not been
>   modified. A public key can be protected from tampering by using its
>   corresponding private master key to sign the public key components and
>   user IDs, thus binding the components to the public master key.
>   Signing public key components with the corresponding private master
>   signing key is called self-signing, and a public key that has
>   self-signed user IDs bound to it is called a certificate.

Here is a sample working code:

```
<?php

$res = gnupg_init();

gnupg_clearsignkeys($res);

$publicKey = file_get_contents('public.key');
$privateKey = file_get_contents('private.key');

$publicImp = gnupg_import($res, $publicKey);
$privateImp = gnupg_import($res, $privateKey);

gnupg_addsignkey($res, $publicImp['fingerprint']);

echo gnupg_geterror($res);
```

The **public.key** content:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0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 =G66f
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The **private.key** content:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0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 =BpXt
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I too have bunch of keys which work for me, anyway will check.